# Algorithm to find number of images (different sizes) that fit on iPad screen

Tags: ios, algorithm, ipad, function, ios7

I have any array of image with sizes like the following,

1. image1 (300,200)
2. image2 (600,200)
3. image3 (1024,768)
4. image4 (340,400)
5. image5 (200,300)
6. image6 (541,768)
7. image7 (120,200)
8. image8 (500,200)
9. image9 (200,200)
10. image10 (285,400)

Basically I want to develop an algorithm or function which can determine the total number of images that can fit on iPad landscape screen[1024 *768] in one `UIViewController`.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a packing problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem).

There are many algorithms, you can start here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/rectanglepacker.aspx

See also:

- http://clb.demon.fi/files/RectangleBinPack.pdf
- http://clb.demon.fi/projects/more-rectangle-bin-packing
- http://kossovsky.net/index.php/2009/07/cshar-rectangle-packing/
- http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2011/5/7/bin_packing/